# Cisco 877 ISR - Joining to another local network

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, vlan

At a remote site I have a  [Cisco 877 ISR](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6202/index.html) providing network services (DHCP, DNS, internet, VPN back to base).  I need to connect it to another companies LAN at the remote site to allow uses to print on the other companies network printer...

The current IOS on the 877 only provides one VLAN for all the four switch ports.  The advanced security version of IOS does give 4 VLANS - one for each port but apparently because the 877 uses ADSL Annex M, we can't upgrade IOS.

I have added the other LAN as an IP on the VLAN interface and have connectivity, but my issues are:

- How to only allow access from the other by the printer's IP address
- How to stop DHCP broadcasts from each network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think it can be done, so have a bought a 2611 to NAT between the networks.